# Python cравнение моделей регрессии

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, numpy

При построении моделей регрессии задался вопросом, как их лучше сравнивать? Какой параметр выбрать и как его найти на питоне?

Например я построил, обучил и попробовал предсказать

```
train = pd.read_csv('state_1.csv',";",header=None)
X_train = train.drop([16,17],axis=1)
Y_train = train[16]

test_data = pd.read_csv('state_2.csv',";",header=None)
X_test = test_data.drop([16,17],axis=1)
Y_test = test_data[16]

normalized_X_train = preprocessing.normalize(X_train)
normalized_X_test = preprocessing.normalize(X_test)

model1 = svm.SVR(kernel='linear', C=1.0)
cl1 = model1.fit(normalized_X_train,Y_train)
predictions1 = cl1.predict(normalized_X_test)

model2 = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=200, max_depth=5)
cl2 = model2.fit(normalized_X_train,Y_train)
predictions2 = cl2.predict(normalized_X_test)
```

На основании каких параметров стоит сравнивать модели? И как их найти с помощью питона(на питон перешел недавно)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно оценивают точность модели на тестовых данных. [Самые популярные метрики для оценки регрессионных моделей](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics):

- [MSE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html#sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error) - Mean Squared Error - [среднеквадратичное отклонение](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#mean-squared-error)
- [MAE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error.html#sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error) - Mean Absolute Error - [среднее абсолютного значения ошибки](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#mean-absolute-error)

Т.е. можно сравнивать одну и ту же метрику для разных моделей или сравнивать показатели одной модели при использовании разных гиперпараметров.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! А как же среднеквадратичное отклонение или коэффициент детерминации? Или это одни и те же метрики просто из разных библиотек?

Comment: @KordDEM, MSE - это оно и есть. Я уже стал забывать русские названия терминов. R2 по ссылке - это коэффициент детерминации

Comment: Да спасибо, с MSE увидел, поправить коммент уже не сумел. Про коэффициент детерминации насколько корректно его использовать?